# How to locate and install Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, service-pack

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on a Windows 7 x86 machine. Microsoft broke the links in their download area, so I can't use the link at [Description of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/983509/description-of-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1). I found it in Microsoft Catalog, but this shows up when I click *Download*:

[image]

I found a download called `vs10sp1-kb983509_90d66d880ef49c9b9a9a0da5e7fc7b2ff907f00e.exe` in the list. The `vs10sp1` and `kb983509` sounds about right. When I attempt to run it, it exits about half way into the *Extracting* portion. It does not provide a message.

How do I locate and install the service pack?

---

Here's the actual problem I am encountering under VS2010. I'm guessing the service pack will resolve it: [Error 'LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt' after installing Visual Studio 2012 Release Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10888391/608639).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421884/is-it-possible-to-download-standalone-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1 -- apparently the easiest way is if you have a MSDN or VS subscription and can use the subscribers' download area.

Comment: @Ramhound - As I understand it, its still available if one purchases an MSDN subscription. Just like the WannaCry update...

Comment: I still have the **VS2010SP1dvd1.iso** . Use Dropbox, [create a file request](https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/create-file-request) and I'll upload it to you.

Comment: Actually, I believe this is still available via Windows Update. Or at least I have it sitting there... https://i.imgur.com/FUDOC6s.png

Comment: @jww any update? do you still care about the ISO or not?

Answer (score 4):

I just found it here:
https://archive.org/download/vs-2010-sp-1dvd-1

Microsoft has deleted it everywhere

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: Does this DVD include all of the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 security and critical updates? Can it be used for multiple languages (e.g. Japanese support)?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I locate and install the service pack?

Recently, I was able to locate older versions of Visual Studio, on the Visual Studio website.  It requires a free subscription in order to download.

[Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads)

[image]

You can download both the web installer and the DVD on this page.

[image]